# How to call pop-up frame upon button click

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I want to have a pop-up frame upon button click in 1 of my module, but I unable to get it. It always attached to my existing opened frame, my existing open frame layout will be overlap by this call out frame.

The follow are what I'm putting into coding:

```
procedure TWidgetFrame1.acBtnExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  WidgetFrame2 := TWidgetFrame2.Create(Owner);
  WidgetFrame2.Parent := TWinControl(Owner);
end;
```

Kindly need help on this~~~~ because this is the 1st time I'm using widget frame.

Comment: I can't understand this. We know nothing about the types. I don't even know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the frame's `Parent` to be its own popup `TForm`, not the `Owner` of the frame that is creating it.

```
procedure TWidgetFrame1.acBtnExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  Frm: TForm;
begin
  Frm := TForm.CreateNew(Owner);
  WidgetFrame2 := TWidgetFrame2.Create(Frm);
  WidgetFrame2.Parent := Frm;
  Frm.Show;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, i got it now. Thx.